# Show only result within 90 days from present date after API grabs the data

Tags: c#, api, datatable, date-arithmetic, date-comparison

I have my code pasted below. Now I'm totally lost on where and what code to insert let's say I want to show only data which has a startdate within (date today - 90 days). Kindly help me please. Been stuck for weeks on this one.

By the way this code will run after it grabs the data from another program through API.

```
public DataTable FGetHasData(int iMode)
    {
        DataTable dtHASDataReturn = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtHASData = new DataTable();
        string sSorter = String.Empty;

        if (iMode.Equals(0))
        {
            try
            {
                dtHASData = this.oHASData.RetrievePayments();


                dtHASData.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Agency Code";
                dtHASData.Columns[1].ColumnName = "Agency Name";
                dtHASData.Columns[2].ColumnName = "Patient Code";
                dtHASData.Columns[3].ColumnName = "Claim Code";
                dtHASData.Columns[5].ColumnName = "Insurance Company Name";
                dtHASData.Columns[6].ColumnName = "Amount";
                dtHASData.Columns[7].ColumnName = "Document Number";
                dtHASData.Columns[8].ColumnName = "To Print";
                dtHASData.Columns[9].ColumnName = "Payment Type";
                dtHASData.Columns[10].ColumnName = "Memo";
                dtHASData.Columns[11].ColumnName = "Balance Type";
                dtHASData.Columns[12].ColumnName = "RAP";
                dtHASData.Columns[13].ColumnName = "Outlier";

                sSorter = "periodstart";
            }                
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.FLogTrans(e.Message.ToString());
                return dtHASDataReturn;
            }

        }
        else if (iMode.Equals(1))
        {
            try
            {
                dtHASData = this.oHASData.RetrieveRemittanceAdvices();

                dtHASData.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Agency Code";
                dtHASData.Columns[1].ColumnName = "Agency Name";
                dtHASData.Columns[3].ColumnName = "Check Amount";
                dtHASData.Columns[4].ColumnName = "Remittance Advice Memo";
                dtHASData.Columns[5].ColumnName = "Insurance Company Name";
                dtHASData.Columns[6].ColumnName = "Amount Paid";
                dtHASData.Columns[7].ColumnName = "Net Reimbursement";
                dtHASData.Columns[8].ColumnName = "Withheld";
                dtHASData.Columns[9].ColumnName = "Document Number";
                dtHASData.Columns[10].ColumnName = "To Print";
                dtHASData.Columns[11].ColumnName = "Payment Type";
                dtHASData.Columns[12].ColumnName = "Memo";

                sSorter = "RADate";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.FLogTrans(e.Message.ToString());
                return dtHASDataReturn;
            }
        }

        DataView dvSorter = new DataView(dtHASData);

        if (this.FConfigVarRetriever(4).Equals("1"))
        {
            int iRowsMany = int.Parse(this.FConfigVarRetriever(5));

            dvSorter.Sort = sSorter + " desc";
            dtHASData = dvSorter.ToTable();

            if (iMode.Equals(0))
            {
                dtHASData.Columns[4].ColumnName = "Period Start";
            }
            else if (iMode.Equals(1))
            {
                dtHASData.Columns[2].ColumnName = "Remittance Advice Date";
            }

            dtHASDataReturn = dtHASData.AsEnumerable().Take(iRowsMany).CopyToDataTable();                
        }
        else if (this.FConfigVarRetriever(4).Equals("2"))
        {
            dvSorter.RowFilter = sSorter + " >= '" + this.FConfigVarRetriever(6) + "'";
            dvSorter.Sort = sSorter + " desc";
            dtHASData = dvSorter.ToTable();

            if (iMode.Equals(0))
            {
                dtHASData.Columns[4].ColumnName = "Period Start";
            }
            else if (iMode.Equals(1))
            {
                dtHASData.Columns[2].ColumnName = "Remittance Advice Date";
            }

            dtHASDataReturn = dtHASData;
        }


        return dtHASDataReturn;
    }
```

Comment: I don't suppose you could just get that data into an IEnumerable (List or something) so we could run a `Where` query on it?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have tried inserting a query but it made me look like a weirdo since API doesn't allow queries but instead the whole data should be pulled from API and then the filter will take place.

Comment: Thats fine, but what does the data come in as? Does it come in as a List or other IEnumerable? Does its *have* to come in as a data table?

Comment: When I GET the data it comes as an Array then I will set it in my grid. Sorry if I'm slow on understanding.

Comment: It comes in as an array, thats good! Is it an array of objects? Could you provide the definition of those objects? Its sounding like we can do this with no problem.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET ---Yes it comes in as Enumerable. How do I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said it comes in as an `IEnumerable`, and I'm going to assume the class has the following structure:

```
public class Record
{
    DateTime StartDate {get; set;}
    //A whole bunch of other stuff
}
```

In that case, we will use a `Where` query to do our filtering, combined with some `DateTime` math and comparison:

```
IEnumerable<Record> results = original.Where(r => r.StartDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90));
```

You would then use "results" wherever you had "original" so you only act on the filtered data.

To respond to the comments:

You can put it wherever you want the filtering to take place. I would put it immediately before you actually try to use it:

```
dtHASData = dtHASData.Where(....);  //Add here
DataView dvSorter = new DataView(dtHASData);
```

Its ok that it comes in as an array, those are `IEnumerable` so the LINQ extensions work on them.

Comment: Where do I put this code Sir? On what line to be exact?Sorry for the question.

Comment: I have a hunch that a filter must be placed here in this part of the code.`dtHASDataReturn = dtHASData.AsEnumerable().Take(iRowsMany).CopyToDataTable();`

Comment: With the answer you gave sir. I'm sorry but I have no code such as the one you gave above. And after carefully studying it it came as an array.

Comment: @PatrickFlorentino, Hopefully the additional information in my edit helps.